# Show that $(A \oplus B) \oplus B = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I having some trouble proving $(A \oplus B)\oplus B = A$, I understand the truth table logic but can someone example to me in theory what the equation mean in set theory?

Comment: By $\oplus$ do you mean exclusive or?

Comment: ya.. sorry about the formatting.. i am new to here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) in logic means : $A \oplus B$ is true iff "one of the two disjuncts is true but noth both".

Thus, the corresponding set operation must means :

> $(x \in A \oplus B)$ **iff** ($x \in A$ or $x \in B$) and not-($x \in A$ and  $x \in B$).

But ($x \in A$ or $x \in B$) is $x \in A \cup B$, while ($x \in A$ and  $x \in B$) is $x \in A \cap B$.

Thus :

> > $(x \in A \oplus B)$ **iff** ($x \in A \cup B$ and not-($x \in A \cap B$)),

i.e.

> > $(A \oplus B) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B)^c.$

Comment: Hi, could u explain from the LHS and RHS? I still don't get it.. any venn diagram to show?

Comment: @user187424 - the Venn diagram is in the Wiki page linked.